# Android: Open default google map application and get the pinned location back

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to open the default google maps application from my application, let the user pin a location, and get the pinned location details back to my application.
somekind of `startActivityForResult()`, where the result data would be a latitude,longitude or anything like that.

is there a way to do this? is it possible?

**PS:** I already know/worked with the maps sdk, but in this application this is the only use case with maps, that's why i can't afford using the sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that with the Google Maps app. Here's a PlacePicker library that accomplishes this task though:

https://github.com/suchoX/PlacePicker

Comment: I have seen this, it has been deprecated and now it requires a maps sdk key and a billing acount...

Comment: No, you're misreading it. The official PlacePicker from Google was deprecated. This is a replacement for that which uses Android's free, built-in Geocoder class.

Comment: But in [here](https://github.com/suchoX/PlacePicker#how-to-use) the first thing it says > You need a Maps API key and add it to your app.

Comment: Yes, you need a Maps API key to display a map in Android.

Comment: But since it uses the geocoder, it won't bill anything, right?

Comment: Correct. The built-in Geocoder functionality is completely free on Android.